# C# FlowLayoutPanel scrollBar

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, scrollbar, flowlayoutpanel

I'm making an instant messaging application in C#.  The problem that I'm facing right now is that for the contacts list I've made a custom `control extending`userControl`, which contains a`FlowLayoutPanel`.

That panel will contain a list of userControls.  I want to customize the `VscrollBar`, but no chance (not possible).  Instead I have this genius idea to hide the `VscrollBar` from the `FlowLayoutPanel`, and make simple buttons (UP and down events).  For this everything worked like a charm, but when I tried to hide the VscrollBar by making the property `autoScroll = false` , the buttons stopped working.

How can I hide the `VscrollBar`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the the vertical bar, there are some possible solutions. ..

- You could make an event for resize, controls add, controls remove and set all the child controls' width to flowlayoutpanel.width -20
- You could add a panel to the flowlayoutpanel and set it to autosize and make the panels may width to flowlayoutpanel.width-20.
- You could check if the width of the flowlayoutpanel is bigger than its real width (means vscrollbar appeared) , and resize the children that it'll/ld hide again
- and if you are sure that your controls are smaller than the flowlayoutpanel's width, you simply could create a panel which covers the vertical bar. (use .BringToFront() to put it before the flowlayoutpanel's scrollbar)

I hope that I understood and perhaps have solved the problem